# How to apply babel loader to `jsnext:main` but not `main`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

With the `jsnext:main` property in `package.json` and tree-shaking, it seems like it would be preferable to use the es6 version and `babel-loader` to get a smaller build than to always import the whole UMD package from `main`.

I know not every package supports `jsnext:main`, but for the ones that do I want to apply `babel-loader` and cherry-pick imports.

Example of es6 package:

```
{
  "name": "module",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "jsnext:main": "src/index.js"
}
```

Example of commonjs or UMD dependency:

```
{
  "name": "module",
  "main": "lib/index.js"
}
```

Right now I exclude all node modules in webpack.

```
{
  test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: "babel-loader"
}
```

Is there some way to configure the loader to include if there is a `jsnext:main` and exclude otherwise? This might be overkill but it seems objectively better to use es6 imports when supported.

Comment: Couldn't you do `exclude: /node_modules(?!\/some_module)/` to exclude all module except the one you want, and call it good?